# Custom Validation or extended validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I have 2 fields that need to be compared against each other but field 2 is not always present so my update validation fails:

```
return [
    'start_filling'  => 'nullable|date|before:end_filling',
    'end_filling'    => 'nullable|date|after_or_equal:start_filling'
];
```

How can I set the condition so that `before:end_filling` only validates when end_filling is present and set.

Comment: The [`required_with`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-with) rule might be helpful.

Comment: It shouldn't be required :) but thanks

Comment: you can use "sometimes" rule

Comment: Sometimes is for the same key, I need it to validate a specific part of the rule if there's a value from another key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rule` class for complex conditions.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

return [
    'start_filling'  => ['nullable', 'date', Rule::when($this->end_filling, 'before:end_filling')],
    'end_filling'    => 'nullable|date|after_or_equal:start_filling'
];
```